# How to determine an image quality by SSIM?

Tags: image, equality, ssim

I used to know that SSIM  is a method for measuring the similarity between two images. 
How to determine the quality of processed image by SSIM score. Is the method has maximum or minimum value as the standard?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) is a method for comparing the perceived similarity between two images. If two images are identical the SSIM value should be 1. A good explaination with Python implementation can be found here:
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ssim.html

Comment: This answer explains how to use `scikit-image` library's `compare_ssim` method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207748/3337089