# How to find PSNR and SSIM of two video files in python using openCV and other libraries?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, ssim

I want to find out PSNR and SSIM of two video files in python using openCv and numpy.
How to find PSNR in python

I tried below code for SSIM

```
# compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
# images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

# threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
# obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

# loop over the contours

for c in cnts:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour and then draw the
        # bounding box on both input images to represent where the two
        # images differ
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(imageA, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(imageB, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the video frames by frames and use this function to compute similarity between frames and find mean.

Make sure you provide full path of the image.

```
def compare(ImageAPath, ImageBPath):
    img1 = cv2.imread(ImageAPath)          # queryImage
    img2 = cv2.imread(ImageBPath)
    image1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)          # trainImage


    score, diff = compare_ssim(image1, image2, full=True,  multichannel=False)
    print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
```

If you Image is colourful and you don't wish to use gray image, pass

```
multichannel=True
```